# How can I get an ID attribute to work inside a span on Visual Studio

Tags: html, css

I am very new to coding. I am trying to put an ID attribute into a span on visual studio but when I try to put ID it is simply coming up as a string instead.

I know this is basic but would appreciate any help.

```
<div>
                    <span>Tip</span>
                    <span>id="tipvalue"</span>
                    
</div>
```

Comment: you need to put the attribute inside the tag like `<span id="tipvalue"></span>`.  What is the issue by typing it in correctly? I fail to see how this is an issue related to visual studio not what the actual issue is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to place the id attribute inside the span tag as well as any other attribute or property. `<span id='myId'>Content</span>`. Everything between the opening and closing tag is considered content of the tag.

Comment: When I do it turns it everything in the span into a string into a string.    <div>
                        <label for="tipinput" id="tippercent">Select tip</label>
                        <span>id='tipinput' >0%</span>
                    </div>

Comment: <div>
                        <label for="tipinput" id="tippercent">Select tip</label>
                        <span>id='tipinput' >0%</span>
                    </div>